# Python property access results in the property object itself

Tags: python-3.x, properties

I've just written this class:

```
class PhysicsObject:
    "An object that is physically simulated. Has velocity, position, and orientation."

    def __init__(self):
        self.velocity=Vector(0,0)
        self.position=Vector(0,0)
        self.heading=0
        #This gives a direction vector that represents the direction the physics object is facing
        self.forward=property(fget=lambda self: Vector(1,0).rotate(self.heading))
        #This gives an integer that represents how fast the object is moving in the direction it's facing
        self.fwdspeed=property(fget=lambda self: self.velocity.dot(self.forward))
        self.mass=1
```

To test it, I wrote this little bit of code:

```
myphysobj=PhysicsObject()
myphysobj.velocity=Vector(15,5)
print("Position:",myphysobj.position,"Facing:",myphysobj.forward,"Forward Speed:",myphysobj.fwdspeed)
```

I expected the result to be something along these lines:

```
Position: (0,0) Facing: (0,0) Forward Speed: 5
```

However, I instead got

```
Position: (0,0) Facing: <property object at 0x02AB2150> Forward Speed: <property object at 0x02AB2180>
```

As I understand it, setting an attribute to the result of `property(fget=myfunc)` should give the result of `myfunc()` when that attribute is accessed. Instead, it seems to be giving me the property object itself. Am I misunderstanding how `property()` is used, or have I committed a more subtle error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`property` is a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), and descriptors are meant to be defined on the class directly rather than on the instance.

```
class PhysicsObject:
  forward = property(fget=lambda self: Vector(1,0).rotate(self.heading))
  fwdspeed = property(fget=lambda self: self.velocity.dot(self.forward))

  def __init__(...):
     ...
```

Comment: Well, I tried that, but now myphysicsobject.forward gives None. Any idea what's going on there? It's also worth noting that the link to the python docs you have is to the 2.7.x edition, while this question is tagged as 3.x.

Comment: It returns `None` because the `Vector.rotate()` method operates in place. The descriptor protocol hasn't changed between 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Wait, does Python come with a Vector class in one of the standard libraries? I wrote my own (whose `rotate()` also operates in-place, but I didn't intend for it to do so).

Comment: It does not. I inferred it by the behavior you described.